# String Splitting PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am wanting to break down a string in to different parts and because of the nature of the string I cant quite get my head around how I could go about doing this or if its possible.

Below is the string that I am trying to break up:

```
"'1,2,3,4','2,4,5,6,4',NULL, NULL,NULL ,'2,3,4,5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL"
```

I would like it like:

```
'1,2,3,4',
'2,4,5,6,4',
NULL,
NULL,
'2,3,4,5'
```

I was thinking of dooing something like this:

```
<?php
    
    $test = 'CALL sp_advert_search_load(\'1,3,4,5\',\'2,4,3\',NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)';
    $test1 = explode( '(',$test);
    $test1 = explode( ',',$test1[1]);
    
    foreach ($test1 as $food){
    
    echo $food."<br />";;
    }
    ?>
```

Then trying to build the array back into strings using the ' and a start and end point somehow.

Anybody any ideas of any better ways to approach this one?

Comment: are you able to solve your issue or are you just looking in for a better performance?

Comment: Your first string and second string are different. Are you trying to parse both or just one? If one, which is it? If you can get this into valid JSON then use `json_decode`, that's probably the best bet. Put brackets around it and sub `'` for `"`.

Comment: @NitinSingh I havent solved the problem.   the string I am starting off with is "CALL sp_advert_search_load('1,2,3', '1,2,3', NULL, '1,2,3', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have 2 problems, but this splits it into two parts anyway.

First is to extract the parameters part from the `CALL`, this finds the first `(` and takes the rest of the string.  Then it uses `rtrim()` to strip off the trailing `)` (also spaces in case any are there).

The second part is to split the string into each parameter.  As it is now effectively a CSV, I use `str_getcsv()` to split with a `'` as the enclosure to keep the groups together...

```
$test = 'CALL sp_advert_search_load(\'1,3,4,5\',\'2,4,3\',NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)';

$params = rtrim(substr($test, strpos($test, "(") + 1), " )");
print_r(str_getcsv($params, ",", "'"));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,3,4,5
    [1] => 2,4,3
    [2] => NULL
    [3] =>  NULL
    [4] =>  NULL
    [5] =>  NULL
    [6] =>  NULL
    [7] =>  NULL
    [8] =>  NULL
    [9] =>  NULL
    [10] =>  NULL
    [11] =>  NULL
    [12] =>  NULL
    [13] =>  NULL
    [14] =>  NULL
    [15] =>  NULL
    [16] =>  NULL
    [17] =>  NULL
    [18] =>  NULL
    [19] =>  NULL
    [20] =>  NULL
    [21] =>  NULL
    [22] =>  NULL
    [23] =>  NULL
    [24] =>  NULL
    [25] =>  NULL
    [26] =>  NULL
    [27] =>  NULL
    [28] =>  NULL
    [29] =>  NULL
    [30] =>  NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is excatly what i was trying to do. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm bored, just extract the stuff between the parentheses and then `eval` it as an array:

```
preg_match('/\(.*\)/', $test, $match);
eval("\$result = array$match[0];");
```

Or:

```
preg_match('/\((.*)\)/', $test, $match);
eval("\$result = [$match[1]];");
```

These will give you actual `NULL` values not string `"NULL"` so you will only see them in a `var_dump`.